# Conditions for something to be called a probability function

Tags: probability, distributions, random-generation, density-estimation

I'm dealing with random walks with an angle. First the angle should be uniformly distributed on interval $[-\pi,\pi]$. This I understand.

But next I need to introduce a modification. By assuming the angle theta with interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ is a random number with probability density $p(\theta)$.
Which conditions must $p(\theta)$ satisfy in order to represent a real probability distribution and, in addition, has the property that it is impossible to step immediately back again?

So far I have understood that for it to represent a real probability distribution. $p(\theta)$ needs to satisfy these conditions to be a real probability density function:

- the function is non-negative everywhere
- the function integrates to one

But I'm having a hard time understand what property it need to have so its impossible to step immediately back again?

Later we assume that $p(\theta) = a\times \cos(b\times\theta)$. I need to determine the constants a and b such that p(phi) satisfies the conditions for a probability density and $p(\pi)=p(-\pi)=0$

Hope that I have explained myself good enough for you to understand. Any help would be so much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "stepping immediately back again"?

Comment: An "angle" would seem--at best--to be only part of the description of a random walk.  Even if it is a direction of a vector, what would the magnitude of that vector be?  I suspect that if you would explain what role this angle plays in the walk, then it would help us understand what you mean by "step back" and thereby respond to the comment by @Tim.

Comment: Google "Kolmogorov Axioms". There's a third one that you are missing about $\sigma-$additivity.

Comment: I'm not sure myself what  "stepping immediately back again" means.
From what I thought it is meant to be so if going in a vector [x,y]. For the next step it can't go [-x,-y]. In other words going back where it came from. But don't really understand what that got to do with the probability density. 

The vector is changes for each loop. So all paths first walks to (1,0). After that this is what effects the next step.
for j from 1 to N do
X[i,j]:=X[i,j-1]+cos(phi);
Y[i,j]:=Y[i,j-1]+sin(phi);

Here sin(phi) and cos(phi) will be random for each loop.

Comment: The chances of hitting negative of the angle you just took are infinitesimally small, since this is a continuous distribution. More importantly, it sounds like your third "step" depends on your second one. In this case, your steps aren't independent and you need a probability distribution that "remembers" previous steps.

Comment: I would, with respect, suggest you ignore all preceding comments.  You have described a random walk with random unit displacements in the plane.  The two conditions you provide are sufficient to define a valid probability.  They are not necessary: there are other probability distributions that have no density. All you require (not to step back again immediately) is that the joint probability of the ordered pair of angles $(\theta, \theta+\pi)$ (taken modulo $2\pi$) equal zero for any value of $\theta$.  (That's automatically satisfied by any distribution having a density.)